# I want to avoid tracking of object in vuforia unity 3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

When I move, the mobile (AR camera) object is also moving with it. I want to avoid this. How can this be done? The object should not follow the camera of mobile devices.

I want output like this image:

[image: Expected output]

Comment: That would actually be the intended behaviour of Vuforia. Seems like you are doing something wrong. Are you using image targets? What is your setup like? We cannot help you when you are giving us zero information.

Comment: No i am not using image target, I just placed cube as child of ar camera. Now that cube is moving with camera. I want to achieve like second image which is provided in above link. Can I achieve this using vuforia?

Comment: Well, if you put a cube as a parent of a camera, then it is a child and it will follow it. So that is exactly the intended behaviour of Unity. It seems you are still not familiar with either Unity or Vuforia. You should read more on both before you proceed to get a better understanding of them. A quick guide for Vuforia : https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/getting-started-with-vuforia-in-unity.html

Comment: Sorry. I placed cube separately.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Vuforia only allows you to place objects on different types of image targets, and if i understood correctly that you want to place an object in a 3D environment without an image target

you can do that but your Cellphone must have a gyroscope, here are some pretty good tutorials you can follow here to achieve that:

http://wirebeings.com/markerless-augmented-reality.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=73ImdGxHnkU

This is a very basic tutorial to start understanding AR, if you want something more complex you need to look into projects like [ARCORE (Android)](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/) and [ARKIT (Iphone)](https://developer.apple.com/arkit/)